# Do '&&' and '||' lie on same row in operator precedence or in different row?

Tags: c, operators, logical-operators, operator-precedence

If they do lie in different row then shouldn't in `Exp1 || Exp2 && Exp3`, `(Exp2 && Exp3)` be evaluated first since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`?

And, If they do lie in same row then shouldn't order of execution be First `(Exp1 || Exp2)` and then `&& Exp3` since both are left associative?

Comment: The relative precedence of `&&` and `||` should have been explained by just about any good text book, tutorial or teacher.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, but there are no such good text books AFAIK. They typically have broken "precedence tables" based on the incorrect and outdated one from K&R.

Comment: "precedence" means grouping, not order of evaluation

Answer (score 4):

`Exp1 || Exp2 && Exp3` is *grouped* as `Exp1 || (Exp2 && Exp3)`, due to *operator precedence*.

Note that `(Exp2 && Exp3)` is only actually *evaluated* if `Exp1` evaluates to 0, and then `Expr3` is *only* evaluated if `Exp2` evalutes to 1. This is called *short-circuiting*.

Their being in a different "row" is not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Operator precedence in C is "as indicated by the syntax", meaning in plain English that each sub chapter of the standard chapter 6.5 is one operator group. The precedence is: first group, highest precedence:

> 6.5 Expressions
>
> 6.5.1 Primary expressions
> 6.5.2 Postfix operators
> 6.5.3 Unary operators
> 6.5.4 Cast operators
> 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators
> 6.5.6 Additive operators
> 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators
> 6.5.8 Relational operators
> 6.5.9 Equality operators
> 6.5.10 Bitwise AND operator
> 6.5.11 Bitwise exclusive OR operator
> 6.5.12 Bitwise inclusive OR operator
> 6.5.13 Logical AND operator
> 6.5.14 Logical OR operator
> 6.5.15 Conditional operator
> 6.5.16 Assignment operators
> 6.5.17 Comma operator

As you can see, Logical AND is a separate group from Logical OR. It appears earlier in the standard so it has higher precedence.

If they had been "in the same row", that is if they would have the same precedence, then the operator associativity would determine how the expression should be parsed. `a || b || c` must be parsed as `(a || b) || c` because the associativity of this operator group is left-to-right.

---

Note that operator precedence only mandates which operands that belong with which operators. It doesn't specify order of evaluation (execution), which is a different but related term.

In your case, operator precedence specifies that `Exp1 || Exp2 && Exp3` is equivalent to

```
Exp1 || (Exp2 && Exp3)
```

The order of evaluation of the `||` operator specifically is a special case, it must evaluate `Exp1` completely first, and if it is false, and only then, evaluate the right-hand operator.

Usually in C, the order of evaluation of operands is not specified though. Take for example `Exp1 | Exp2`, where no special rule of order of evaluation exists. Then either `Exp1` or `Exp2` could be evaluated first.